# Lyx: "Undefined control sequence" when using "preccurlyeq"

Tags: lyx

When I try using `\preccurlyeq` in math in lyx, and then compile I get error: `Undefined control sequence`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go do Document > Settings > Math Options and then make sure "amssymb" is set to "Load automatically". If that doesn't work, change it to "Load always".

In the future (and also here if the above does not work), please always post a .lyx minimal example. For more information, read this:  https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: thanks!! worked perfectly!
will do this in the future!